# Compare values from different tables

Tags: mysql

I wanted to find matching records from the column of a table1 to the other column in table2. It has to compare and if it matches then produce output of values from Table1.

| Column b |
| --- |
| 12345 |
| 567890 |
| 1256 |
| 78905 |

And table2

| Column A |
| --- |
| 123456 |
| 56789 |
| 34890 |
| 789056 |

Output needed something like this:

| result |
| --- |
| 12345 |
| 567890 |
| 78905 |

```
select
    t2.column a,
    case when exists (select * from table1 t1 where t1.column b in (t2.column a )
        then 'Matched'
        else 'Unmatched'
    end matched
from table2 t2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use an INNER JOIN:

```sql
SELECT table1.columnB
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.columnA = table1.columnB
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/t8WpY_Qs)

P.S. Next time do not provide output like "needed something like this", but provide expected output based on the given input. (This is why the DbFiddle does not use the exact input data that is given in the question)

EDIT: Because " if the first 5 digits matches with the table2 column values then I would need that also to be displayed. "

```sql
SELECT
   columnB as result
FROM table1
CROSS JOIN table2 ON LEFT(table2.columnA,LEAST(length(columnB),length(columnA))) = 
                     LEFT(table1.columnB,LEAST(length(columnB),length(columnA)))
```

see last part of [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/uB5T2BXp)

[LEAST](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least) will returns the smallest (minimum-valued) argument, so only the first part of the values in both column will be compared, and MySQL will *automatically* convert then to a string before taking the LEFT part of it.

Comment: In your fiddle you do not use the OP's sample data. If you did you would see that your query does not return the OP's expected result.

Comment: Hi thanks. But with Innerjoin it displays exact matching values. For ex: if the first 5 digits matches with the table2 column values then I would need that also to be displayed.

Comment: @vid:  That seems to be an important details that is missing from your question.

Comment: Sorry for that.

Comment: I did do an edit on the answer.

Comment: great. I just have doubt may be if it’s silly when we use ```select column b as result``` can’t we treat result as another column and then compare this result with other column of table ?

Comment: I am trying to understand what you want to do but, I could not think of an reason why treat `result` as another column would benefit anything.

Comment: `INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.columnA LIKE CONCAT( table1.columnB, '%') OR  table1.columnB LIKE CONCAT( table2.columnA, '%')`

Comment: @Roemer: The explain plan looks the same, so this seems to be an alternative to this solution.  (see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/7hY61Wiq) for the explain plans)

Comment: It is. I typed it before the edit in the solution, but discovered I hadn't hit enter only an hour later. I hit it and there was a similar solution. Nice to have two different options, tho. Depends on taste which one you find clearer, I find mine much easier to read.

Comment: Nice fiddle by the way!

Comment: When I compare values of two different tables seems like it takes forever it blocks whole system. Any other way we could do it

Comment: @vid: This can take some time when there is no index on `columnB` and/or not index on `columnB`.  I suggest creating such an index.    For the complete answer I would suggest to do some [research](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+improve+performance+mysql+query+site%3Astackoverflow.com), and when you cannot solve it ask another (new) question. The new question should hold info about the number of records and the `SHOW CREATE TABLE ..` statement for both tables.